# How to show label properties on the map from GeoJson?

Tags: android, mapbox

I have developed map using mapbox SDK for Android opensource. I have a  geoJson file with properties and lat and lang using this I have created the map.

The problem I am facing is how to show properties on the map, e.g. ('P11/03').

sample GeoJson:

```json
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GIS_LINK": "NHC_P11\/03", "IND_EST": "NHC_P11", "BLOCK": "P11\/03", "FIELD": "P11" }
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Check this  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/geojson

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapbox Studio to upload your own data and create custom basemaps. You can read more about [uploading data to Mapbox Studio here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/uploads/).

Alternatively, you can use the upcoming Runtime Style API if you want to handle this client side. You have a full working example in the [`GeojsonLayerInStackActivity`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/GeojsonLayerInStackActivity.java) of the Mapbox demo app.